# How to destroy bootstrap colorpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I am using bootstrap colorpicker in my logic as given below : -

```
    for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
     if (selectedValue == abc[i].name) {                
        var color = getColor(selectedValue);                
        $('.colorPicker').colorpicker('setValue', color).on(
                            'changeColor', function(ev) {
                                var colorCode = ev.color.toHex();
                                changeColor(colorCode);
                            }).on('hidePicker', function(ev) {
                        alert("Hiding colorpicker");
                    }); 
               }
   }
```

The above code gets called from a method everytime a user select some value in dropdown.

**Problem :**
Now when I open the colorpicker and close it by defocusing it. I get the alert "Hiding colorpicker" once in first go.
If I select another value from dropdown that fires the above given code again and then I open and close the color picker again. The I get the alert twice and so on in increasing numbers.

**My Understanding:**
My understanding is that I am initializing color picker with different values everytime the above code is fired ,So code is creating different instances of colorpicker on same ".colorPicker" class element. So I need to remove the previously created instance of colorPicker before initializing a new one.

**What I tried:**
I used the below given line as the first line in my method to destroy this first. But it's not working.

```
$('.colorPicker').colorpicker('destroy');
```

Any help that how can I destroy the colorpicker everytime and then use the new instance on every method call so that I can avoid multiple alerts of "Hiding colorpicker".

Comment: Instead of constantly creating and removing instances, you should perhaps just create only one instance in the first place? Since your code snippets lacks any information on how/when that `for` loop is run, that’s all there can be said about this issue at this time. (And your question lacks the information _what_ colorpicker you are using as well. Bootstrap doesn’t provide one by default AFAIK, so you must be using some kind of plugin – which one?)

Comment: http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/